# how can I get the index of a table cell having an input when the input value is changed

Tags: blazor

I'm a beginner in both c# and Blazor, so my question may seem trivial.

I have a table with one row having input components.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>X2</th>
        @foreach (var item in Data)
        {
            <td><input type="number" min="0" max="360" step="1" @onchange="ItemChanged"></td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the code I have a list of double as shown below.
I also have an ItemChanged function which is triggered when the user changes the value of an input

```
@code {
    public List<double> Data = new List<double>{1.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.4};
    
    public void ItemChanged(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        Data[1] = Convert.ToDouble(args.Value);
    }
```

The issue I have is to get the index of the cell containing the input who got the value changed.
So I could change the Data[1] to  Data[index] in my code.

Thank you

Comment: While @maciek answer below is correct, is this a case of "Primitive Obsession"?  The doubles represent something.  Create an object that defines what you are representing.  You can then use `foreach` on the list of the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is I would change to:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>X2</th>
        @for(int i=0; i < Data.Count(); i++)
        { 
            int b=i;
            <td><input type="number" min="0" max="360" step="1" @onchange="args =>ItemChanged(args,b)"></td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>

@indx
```

And the function:

```
@code {
    public List<double> Data = new List<double>{1.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.4};
    
    public int indx = 0;

    public void ItemChanged(ChangeEventArgs args, int index)
    {
        Data[index] = Convert.ToDouble(args.Value);
        indx = index;
    }
}
```

https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GGFGFPvX06jDD4rL39

Comment: I don't have Windows machine to check the code, cause it's weekend...

Comment: why do you need Windows machine for that? Also blazor repl exists.

Comment: I have VS installed on a Windows machine, and it's weekend. In the West people mostly don't work on the weekend. But feel free to answer the question ;)

Comment: haha. I got it. Your specific need. You answer is good!